# writerow() or writerows() loops

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have the following code:

```
import csv
input_file = csv.reader(open('template.csv','r+')) #template.csv has 10 lines
output = open('output.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

elem = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in elem:
    wr.writerows(input_file)
```

Since the file 'template.csv' has 10 lines, I expect an output of 10 x 5 lines - but only 10 appears.

How do I nest the writerow/rows loop?

Answer (score 6):

You `input_file` is an iterator, and once exhausted won't rewind to the beginning for you. Store the result in a list and write that:

```
input_file = csv.reader(open('template.csv','r+')) #template.csv has 10 lines
input_lines = list(input_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

**writerows** : will create a csv depending on the rules you set in the csv.writer  e.g.

```
wr = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\n') #this will output each element in input_file 
                                         #as a separate line

#Loop it 5 times you should have your 5 x 10 lines printed to the file
for i in elem[0:4]:
    wr.writerows(input_file)
```